# Evaluating test dataset

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-science

For most competitions, the data is split into a training data and test data. I worked on the training data(spliting it into x_train...) and created a model, i evaluated it and got the respective accuracy score. I used the same model to predict the test dataset that was left out, however, when i tried to evaluate the models performance, i kept getting this error below:
Could anyone explain what am doing wrong? and give ways to remedy it.

The Code:

```
# logistic regression

logreg_main_test = logreg.predict(main_test_scaled) # predict

# evaluate
logreg_score_main_test = accuracy_score(Y_test, logreg_main_test)
f1_val_main_test = f1_score(Y_test, logreg_score_main_test)
recall_val_main_test = recall_score(Y_test, logreg_score_main_test)

# display result
print('Model accuracy:',logreg_score_main_test)
```

The output error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-8265b6fa0a29> in <module>
      4 
      5 # evaluate
----> 6 logreg_score_main_test = accuracy_score(Y_test, logreg_main_test)
      7 f1_val_main_test = f1_score(Y_test, logreg_score_main_test)
      8 recall_val_main_test = recall_score(Y_test, logreg_score_main_test)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    330     uniques = np.unique(lengths)
    331     if len(uniques) > 1:
--> 332         raise ValueError(
    333             "Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: %r"
    334             % [int(l) for l in lengths]

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [4705, 10086]
```

Comment: check shape: Y_test and  logreg_main_test

Comment: Are you sure `main_test_scaled` is not the whole dataset (train and test)?

Comment: its the whole dataset, the train set had a shape of 23k and main_test set had a shape of 10k

Answer (score 0):

The length(number of samples) in your truth labels doesn't match with the number of samples in your predicted labels.
Check the length of your **Y_test** and **logreg_main_test**, it should match if not then either your split is incorrect or you are trying to predict with the train split instead of test split.

Comment: Indeed i did just that. How do you suggest i evaluate the test set?

Comment: To evaluate predictions, first you need to make sure predicted outputs and your test samples have the same length.

Comment: Does the length/shape of your Y_test and logreg_main_test match? 
If yes, then you shouldn't get this error.

Answer (score 0):

there is a mismatch in the number of samples between the true labels (Y_test) and the predicted labels (logreg_main_test)

you should make sure that the shape of the test data is the same as the shape of the training data before you use the trained model to make predictions. You can do this by preprocessing the test data in the same way as the training data. Specifically, you should apply the same feature scaling or normalization that you applied to the training data to the test data.

You can try the following below:

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X_train)
X_train_scaled = scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)
```